# corner like in maps App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need a corner like in the Maps app.

[image]

I tried this code but nothing happens:

```
- (IBAction) performCurl {
// Curl the image up or down
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:(notCurled ? @"mapCurl" : @"mapUnCurl")];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
notCurled = !notCurled;
[[topView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageFlipAnimation"];
```

}

This my test-project: http://isolute.de/downloads/cornertest2.zip

Answer (score 1):

This was made available in iOS 3.2 and later

```
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```

> When the view controller is presented, one corner of the current view curls up to reveal the modal view underneath. On dismissal, the curled up page unfurls itself back on top of the modal view. A modal view presented using this transition is itself prevented from presenting any additional modal views.
>
> This transition style is supported only if the parent view controller is presenting a full-screen view and you use the UIModalPresentationFullScreen modal presentation style. Attempting to use a different form factor for the parent view or a different presentation style triggers an exception.

Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared in [UIViewController.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652432/iphone-page-curl-without-uiviewanimation) for one solution.

Note however that this answer uses `[animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO]`. According to [a forum post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1983-maps-application-curl-animation.html), apps have been rejected for using this undocumented API method.

Also, the mapCurl animation type is undocumented, and apps have been rejected for using it as well.